# How to programmatically resend messages that have faulted with EasyNetQ?

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq, easynetq

I am wondering how to resend messages that have faulted with EasyNetQ, programmatically, without using [HosePipe](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/Re-Submitting-Error-Messages-With-EasyNetQ.Hosepipe), that is to resend to their original target queue using their original sending exchange.

Is it possible, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with is:

```
public static class AdvancedBusExtensions
{
    public static async Task ResendErrorsAsync(this IAdvancedBus source, string errorQueueName)
    {
        var errorQueue = await source.QueueDeclareAsync(errorQueueName);
        var message = await source.GetMessageAsync(errorQueue);
        while (message != null)
        {
            var utf8Body = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);
            var error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Error>(utf8Body);
            var errorBodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(error.Message);
            var exchange = await source.ExchangeDeclareAsync(error.Exchange, x =>
            {
                // This can be adjusted to fit the exchange actual configuration 
                x.AsDurable(true);
                x.AsAutoDelete(false);
                x.WithType("topic");
            });
            await source.PublishAsync(exchange, error.RoutingKey, true, error.BasicProperties, errorBodyBytes);
            message = await source.GetMessageAsync(errorQueue);
        }
    }
}
```